# How can I use values of custom type in ConfigurationSection?

Tags: c#, configurationsection

Let's say I have type `Point2D` (this is **example**), how can I use this type with `ConfigurationSection` -- in other words, what methods I have to implement in order value of my type be created from string.

One way would be to provide `TypeConverter`, is there another way? Without introducing extra types, solely within my custom type (in this example `Point2D`)?

*Another way, but it is more a trick, would be for example having properties `x` and `y` of know type `int`, and then provide creator property to get `Point2D` -- I don't want to go that path.*

**Update:** Example as requested:

```
public sealed class MyConfig : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("LeftPoint", IsRequired = true),
        TypeConverter(typeof(Point2DTypeConverter))]
    public Point2D LeftPoint
    {
        get { return (Point2D )this["LeftPoint"]; }
        set { this["LeftPoint"] = value; }
    }

    ...
}
```

as you can see I use type converter for `Point2D` and it works. No problem. However I wonder if it would be possible to do conversion (parsing really from string) inside my type `Point2D` so I could remove entire converter (not as attribute tag, but completely).

Comment: use some serialization to local files is enough, why must put in config files?

Comment: Why would you want to put your point in configuration section?

Comment: @LeiYang, I have to put in configuration file, this is requirement.

Comment: this is bad requirement

Comment: Guys, I am not asking about how/why to ditch config files, my question is about `ConfigurationSection` type. And I ask how it converts strings into given type -- is this conversion doable without `TypeConverter` or not. That's it. Please put your judgments how software should be written on other day, thank you.

Comment: in config file there' only string.

Comment: @LeiYang, in config files there are strings, in your/my config **type** there are given types, like `Point2D`. So `ConfigurationSection` somehow converts strings to your/my type. One way of this conversion is `TypeConverter`, is any other mechanism of conversion?

Comment: Would `implicit conversion operator` be of help here?

Comment: @OfirWinegarten, thank you, just checked, it is ignored.

Comment: Would be good to provide your code for configuration section so that we know exactly what you mean.

Comment: @Evk, I updated the question.

Comment: I think there is no way to do that without TypeConverter, because of how it works internally. When ConfigurationSection is parsed - it will always look for type converter for given property type (if it does not inherit from ConfigurationElement) and fail it none can be found. The whole config files system in .NET is unintuitive, inextensible and hard to use, that's why people trying to avoid it at all costs. I don't remember to ever creating custom config sections in at least last 6 years.

Comment: @Evk, my personal decision would be the same, it is a tragic system, but as I wrote, this is a requirement (and I don't make those). Anyway, could you post your comment as answer, then I would accept it as solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TypeConverter` is required in one form or another for `ConfigurationProperty`. If you don't provide one - it will look for it with `TypeDescriptor.GetConverter` if necessary. For that to work your type itself should be decorated with `TypeConverter` attribute, so you cannot get rid of it this way (though you can move responsibility of conversion to the type itself). You can also use generic `TypeConverter`, but for that you need to pass target type to it which is not possible using `ConfigurationProperty` attribute (but is possible if you configure your properties manually, without using attributes). All in all - there is always TypeConverter involved.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's a solid requirement, I would suggest using [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) to convert to and from a string.

`string MyPoint = Json.Serialize(MyPointObject)`

`Point2d MyPoint = Json.Deserialize(ConfigurationSection..)`

You also may abstract your serialization logic by creating custom `ConfigurationSections` as explained here: [How:To Create Custom ConfigurationSections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, I am not marking it as solution, since it as external mechanism as using `TypeConverter`.

Comment: You said "Without introducing extra types" not without extra mechanisms. Update to answer incoming.

Comment: actually, I need about a couple hours to get an update to this answer written.  Basically, it would be creating the custom config section to handle a `Section` of Point, with `Elements` of `X` and `Y`.

Comment: Oh no, I know how to split into config elements, I am thinking about single value which is parsed -- think of TimeSpan for example.